# Magento 2.4.2 shows 404 page in apache server

Tags: .htaccess, magento2

I freshly installed Magento 2.4.2 via composer in the apache server in the subdirectory named "migrate-test"

Here I modified the .htaccess file as per requirement

Original .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Mofiled .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /migrate-test/pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Stores base URL is "https://example.com/migrate-test/"

Now I try to access the baseURL all pages showing 404-page content.

And when I try to append index.php in the URL like this "https://example.com/migrate-test/index.php" at that time it is working fine. But I don't want index.php in the URL.

So if anyone has the solution to this. Then please help me

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please confirm from rule `RewriteRule .* /migrate-test/pub/$0 [L]` what you are trying to rewrite here? Also if possible do let us know more clearly like FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect? Thank you.

Comment: Had a similar problem, there is an issue logged in Github [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32285)

Comment: did anyone find the solution for this issue?